# Writing modular scripts to process MQTT records

Tags: scripting, mqtt

I am in the process of implementing a home automation system that will consist on multiple hardware "nodes" publishing values to a central MQTT server and acting on value changes of a topic that node is subscribed to... Standard MQTT stuff!

However, my problem is finding a technology/language/package/etc.. which will subscribe to a topic, and when its value changes it will perform a bit of logic and change values on other topics..

As an example:

Node 1 detects movement -> updates topic value to "TRUE" -> Script performs some logic now event is true and sets 4 other topics as "TRUE" - Node 3,4,5,6 act on this by performing an action such as switch on a light..

Now I know I could do this within C#! But I am looking for a more... Simple scripting solution I can add new modules into when new nodes come online and create/update new topics. within C# it would be a case of adding new functionality and then recompiling, deploying.. I just need something I can knock a quick 10-15 min script together and the functionality is in place!

I hope this makes sense... I'm finding it hard to explain...

Comment: Maybe have a look at http://www.openhab.org or https://github.com/jpmens/mqttwarn/

Answer (score 0):

Node.JS?

There is nice MQTT library to use (https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt)

Or may be have a look at Node-RED as a quick/simple way to wire together flows like this.

http://nodered.org